# PHP exploding url from text, possible?

Tags: php, html, url, youtube, explode

i need to explode youtube url from this line:

```
[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3HQMbQAWRc[/embed]
```

It is possible? I need to delete [embed] & [/embed].

Comment: `preg_replace("/\[\/?embed\]/","", $url)`

Answer (score 2):

preg_match is what you need.

```
<?php

$str = "[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3HQMbQAWRc[/embed]";
preg_match("/\[embed\](.*)\[\/embed\]/", $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3HQMbQAWRc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3HQMbQAWRc[/embed]';
$string = str_replace(['[embed]', '[/embed]'], '', $string);
```

See [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

why not use str_replace? :) Quick & Easy
http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Please do not ask clarifying questions in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just for good measure, you can also use positive [lookbehind's and lookahead's](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) in your regular expressions:

```
(?<=\[embed\])(.*)(?=\[\/embed\])
```

You'd use it like this:

```
$string = "[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3HQMbQAWRc[/embed]";
$pattern = '/(?<=\[embed\])(.*)(?=\[\/embed\])/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo $match[1];
```

---

Here is an explanation of the regex:

`(?<=\[embed\])` is a Positive Lookbehind - matches something that follows something else.

`(.*)` is a Capturing Group - `.` matches any character (except a newline) with the Quantifier: `*` which provides matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible. This is what is matched between the groups prior to and after. This *are* the droids you're looking for.

`(?=\[\/embed\])` is a Positive Lookahead - matches things that come before it.